# Smallest cardinality of finite algebraic structure whose quasi-equational theory is not finitely based?

Tags: universal-algebra

I understand that, for the set $\{0,1\}$ and any finite number of constants and operations on that set, the resulting algebraic structure has a finite basis of identities. But, does there exist a finite algebraic structure on $\{0,1\}$ whose quasi-equational theory is not finitely based? If not, is there such a structure on $\{0,1,2\}$? What is the smallest cardinality of a possible example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**does there exist a finite algebraic structure on {0,1} whose quasi-equational theory is not finitely based?**

No, there does not exist a $2$-element algebra in a finite signature that has a nonfinitely axiomatizable quasiequational theory. This is the content of the main result of

V. A. Gorbunov
Quasi-identities of two-element algebras
Algebra and Logic 22, 83-88 (1983)

which states

**THEOREM.** Each two-element algebra of finite signature generates a minimal finitely based quasivariety.

---

**If not, is there such a structure on {0,1,2}?**

Yes. In 1977, Gorbunov published an example of a $3$-element algebra with $2$ unary operations that does not have a finitely axiomatizable quasiequational theory.
Later, in 1980, Mark Sapir published a proof that the $3$-element, 1-generated  semigroup $C_{3,1} = \{x, x^2, x^3=x^4\}$ does not have a finitely axiomatizable quasiequational theory.

V. A. Gorbunov
Covers in lattices of quasivarieties and the independent axiomatizability.
 Algebra i Logika 16(5):507-548, 1977.

M. V. Sapir
On the quasivarieties generated by finite semigroups
Semigroup Forum 20(1):73-88, 1980

Comment: +1 as usual. Also, Sapir's example is given by Benjamin Steinberg at [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154017/counterexamples-in-universal-algebra) (possibly with a minor typo?) which the OP may be separately interested in.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I added a comment to Steinberg's answer concerning the error.